# GAM factor smooth interaction--include main effect smooth?

Tags: r, interaction, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am working with a dataset it which I am interested in modeling an age*sex interaction in the GAMM framework. From examples I have seen and documentation I have read, this is typically accomplished by setting sex as an ordered factor and testing the following model:

1. `y ~ ordered_sex + s(age, by = ordered_sex)`

When done this way, the smooth term is significant and the effect is strong. However, there is a very strong effect of age itself, and I am not sure if this is driving the factor smooth effect as well, since the variance explained by age is not accounted for anywhere else (`y ~ s(age)` is wildly significant).

When I run the model this way, accounting for the age effect,

2. `y ~ ordered_sex + s(age) + s(age, by = ordered_sex)`

the factor smooth term is no longer significant.

Is this second model a valid way of accounting for variance explained by age? Given the difference in the significance of the factor smooth term in these two models, is it correct to assume that the age effect was driving the factor smooth effect in model 1?

Note all models are being run with `gamm` (there are repeated measures) in `R`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, AIC and BIC prefer model 2. Is this good evidence for choosing that model?

Comment: I don’t have a rigorous answer, but have you looked at the marginal plots of your smooths in the different models? It does sound like `ordered_sex` might not make much difference. Side-question: is`ordered_sex` actually an ordered factor? Probably doesn’t make a difference in your model, but it would have an effect with some tools.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to be careful with *ordered* factors here in *mgcv* as they aren't doing what I think you want to be fitting.

If you pass an *ordered* factor to `by`, then `gam()` etc set up a smooth for all the levels *except* the reference level, and further more they are set up as smooth differences between the reference level and the level for a specific smooth. What is happening in your first model is that the reference level of `age` is modelled as a constant term (it is the intercept), with the effect of `age` for the other levels being smooth *differences* from this constant.

In the second model, you add `s(age)`, which then models the smooth effect of `age` in the reference level. Now, the `by` smooths model smooth differences from this no-longer-constant reference smooth.

I suspect that in the second model, all the levels of `sex` respond similarly to `age` hence there are no large deviations from the smooth for the reference level of `sex` and hence the terms are not significant. In the first model, the effect of `age` for the reference level was constant, so the difference smooths picked up the actual non-linear effect of `age` and hence were significantly different from zero.

If you just want to estimate a model with separate smooth function of `age` for each level of `sex` I would use an **un**ordered factor (`factor(..., ordered = FALSE)`, not `ordered()` or `factor(..., ordered = TRUE)`. The the model would be:

```
y ~ fsex + s(age, by = fsex)
```

where `fsex` is the unordered factor.

If you want the model to be explicitly set up like ANOVA contrasts (estimate an effect for the reference level then have differences between individual levels and the reference), then you need to fit the model as per your second example with and ordered factor

```
y ~ osex + s(age) + s(age, by = osex)
```

where `osex` is the ordered factor. But note that in this model, `s(age)` is **not** the main smooth effect of `age`. It is the smooth effect of `age` *in the reference level of* `osex`.

Comment: Great, this clarifies things nicely. The goal here is to see if there is a _difference_ in the age effect between the sexes. That is why I was using ordered factors. From your description, including `s(age)` as a term in the model--and allowing that to become the reference smooth that the difference is compared to--seems like the ideal model to test the hypothesis. Much appreciated!