# Interpreting significance of difference between two GAM smoothed series?

Tags: r, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

My question is about statistical interpretation of a two-level
categorical fixed effect in a GAM model regarding the difference between
two groups. Altough I found information about the construction of such
models, for example
here:

- [GAM factor smooth interaction--include main effect smooth?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416991/gam-factor-smooth-interaction-include-main-effect-smooth?rq=1)
- https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/

I could not find concrete guidance about the significance values and
their meaning in model summary, particularly regarding the effect of the
categorical variable.

---

I have two time series of soil moisture measurements over time, obtained in two locations: sun and shade.

Here is reproducible R code to recreate the data:

```r
dat = structure(list(day = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 
103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 
103, 104, 105, 106, 107), location = c("sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", "sun", 
"sun", "sun", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", 
"shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade", "shade"), value = c(0.19688255, 
0.20738015, 0.21831515, 0.2179871, 0.2166749, 0.2133944, 0.2133944, 
0.20563055, 0.2201741, 0.2223611, 0.2166749, 0.21569075, 0.2116448, 
0.20738015, 0.2059586, 0.1989602, 0.19557035, 0.1878065, 0.1832138, 
0.17698085, 0.1622186, 0.14680025, 0.12230585, 0.09628055, 0.07747235, 
0.0935468, 0.0834866, 0.07550405, 0.070802, 0.06588125, 0.06216335, 
0.05735195, 0.0541808, 0.0524312, 0.0502442, 0.04838525, 0.04619825, 
0.04576085, 0.04357385, 0.042371, 0.0316547, 0.0296864, 0.03088925, 
0.0296864, 0.0279368, 0.0279368, 0.02717135, 0.02717135, 0.02498435, 
0.02585915, 0.02717135, 0.02498435, 0.0242189, 0.02585915, 0.02585915, 
0.02498435, 0.0242189, 0.0242189, 0.0242189, 0.02498435, 0.0242189, 
0.0220319, 0.0237815, 0.0207197, 0.0207197, 0.0189701, 0.0176579, 
0.0207197, 0.0198449, 0.0185327, 0.0176579, 0.0189701, 0.0220319, 
0.0207197, 0.0189701, 0.0207197, 0.0215945, 0.0185327, 0.0198449, 
0.0189701, 0.0207197, 0.0207197, 0.0220319, 0.0189701, 0.0189701, 
0.0189701, 0.01536155, 0.01623635, 0.01623635, 0.0176579, 0.0185327, 
0.0189701, 0.0185327, 0.0185327, 0.0189701, 0.0185327, 0.2315, 
0.2274, 0.2241, 0.2216, 0.2174, 0.2104, 0.2061, 0.2008, 0.2143, 
0.2104, 0.2035, 0.1963, 0.1898, 0.182, 0.1783, 0.1738, 0.1671, 
0.1615, 0.1514, 0.147, 0.1416, 0.1357, 0.1317, 0.1276, 0.1266, 
0.1128, 0.1036, 0.0963, 0.092, 0.0875, 0.0841, 0.0797, 0.0768, 
0.0752, 0.0732, 0.0715, 0.0695, 0.0691, 0.0671, 0.066, 0.0562, 
0.0544, 0.0555, 0.0544, 0.0528, 0.0528, 0.0521, 0.0521, 0.0501, 
0.0509, 0.0521, 0.0501, 0.0494, 0.0509, 0.0509, 0.0501, 0.0494, 
0.0494, 0.0494, 0.0501, 0.0494, 0.0474, 0.049, 0.0462, 0.0462, 
0.0446, 0.0434, 0.0462, 0.0454, 0.0442, 0.0434, 0.0446, 0.0474, 
0.0462, 0.0446, 0.0462, 0.047, 0.0442, 0.0454, 0.0446, 0.0462, 
0.0462, 0.0474, 0.0446, 0.0446, 0.0446, 0.0413, 0.0421, 0.0421, 
0.0434, 0.0442, 0.0446, 0.0442, 0.0442, 0.0446, 0.0442)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 53L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 
116L, 117L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 
172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 
205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
216L))
```

And here is what the first/last six rows look like:

```r
head(dat)
```

```
##   day location     value
## 1   0      sun 0.1968825
## 2   1      sun 0.2073802
## 3   2      sun 0.2183152
## 4   3      sun 0.2179871
## 5   4      sun 0.2166749
## 6   5      sun 0.2133944
```

```r
tail(dat)
```

```
##     day location  value
## 211 102    shade 0.0442
## 212 103    shade 0.0446
## 213 104    shade 0.0442
## 214 105    shade 0.0442
## 215 106    shade 0.0446
## 216 107    shade 0.0442
```

The following plot visualizes the two time series (“sun” location in
red, “shade” location in
blue).

```r
plot(dat$day[dat$location == "sun"], dat$value[dat$location == "sun"], type = "b", col = "red", ylim = range(dat$value), xlab = "Day", ylab = "value")
points(dat$day[dat$location == "shade"], dat$value[dat$location == "shade"], type = "b", col = "blue")
```

[image: plot1]

My goal is to statistically evaluate whether the “sun” and “shade”
location differ, i.e., was soil moisture in the “sun” lower/higher/same
compared to “shade” over the study period.

Since the temporal trend is non-linear and wasn’t sure it’s resembling a
particular function, I decided to use a GAM as follows:

```r
library(mgcv)

dat$location = factor(dat$location)
fit = gam(value ~ location + s(day, by = location), data = dat, method = "REML")
```

Following the suggestions in
[GAM factor smooth interaction--include main effect smooth?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416991/gam-factor-smooth-interaction-include-main-effect-smooth?rq=1)

Here is the summary of the model:

```r
summary(fit)
```

```
## 
## Family: gaussian 
## Link function: identity 
## 
## Formula:
## value ~ location + s(day, by = location)
## 
## Parametric coefficients:
##               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  0.0881198  0.0005032  175.12   <2e-16 ***
## locationsun -0.0166002  0.0007116  -23.33   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Approximate significance of smooth terms:
##                        edf Ref.df    F p-value    
## s(day):locationshade 8.364  8.884 1621  <2e-16 ***
## s(day):locationsun   8.889  8.996 2400  <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## R-sq.(adj) =  0.995   Deviance explained = 99.5%
## -REML = -684.71  Scale est. = 2.4308e-05  n = 192
```

and the plot:

```r
plot(fit, shade = TRUE, pages = 1, scale = 0, seWithMean = TRUE)
```

[image: plot2]

Based on the `locationsun` estimate in the `Parametric coefficients`
section (`-0.0166002`, p<0.001), I conclude that indeed the two series
are different, and, specifically, **soil moisture was significantly lower
in the sun than in the shade**.

My question is whether this interpretation is correct? Will be happy to
hear any thoughts.

Comment: No, you can't only consider the parametric effects since you fit separate smoothers. Do you have to produce a p-value? Looking at the plot, I'd say no test required since the curves are obviously different.

Comment: @Roland Thanks! I see... Then, does it make sense to fit one smoother for both, plus a fixed additive effect that represents how much, on average, one curve is "shifted" from the other? As for your question: no, I don't have to produce p-values, but I have to objectively conclude whether the curves are different or not in some way. Sure, visually they look different, but I need a quantitative measure to support this claim.

Comment: My first idea was doing `fit0 <- gam(value ~ s(day), data = dat, method = "REML"); anova(fit, fit0, test = "Chisq")` but then I read `help("anova.gam")` and developed some doubts.